# Do native Haskell lists have a "real" type name? Or... what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: haskell

Following the article about [Haskell type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_families), I found the courage to try it myself. Well knowing that Lists are already Applicative and whatnot, just to see if I got the ideas right, I tried to do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Iterable c where
    data Iterator c :: * -> *
    current :: Iterator c a -> Maybe a
    next :: Iterator c a -> Maybe (Iterator c a)

instance Iterable [] where
    data Iterator [] a = ListIterator [a] -- Problem in this line!
    current (ListIterator []) = Nothing
    current (ListIterator (x:xs)) = Just x
    next (ListIterator []) = Nothing
    next (ListIterator (x:xs)) = Just (ListIterator xs)
```

This is in analogy of the example code given in the above haskell tutorial.
What this is supposed to do is, to implement the type family `Iterable` for native Haskell lists, generically.

I tried alternatively to write `data Iterator [a] = ListIterator [a]` but this yields the same error message as the code I show here:

```
 temp.hs:8:19: error:
    * Expecting one more argument to `[]'
      Expected a type, but `[]' has kind `* -> *'
    * In the first argument of `Iterable', namely `[]'
      In the instance declaration for `Iterable []'
```

Hence, my question, if I have an option to use the real type name for lists instead of `[]`, as I suspect, this is where my (syntactical?) problem is coming from.

Comment: Haskell has not really "*native*" lists I think. Lists are not something that has to be implemented by a Haskell compiler, it is defined as a datastructure `data [a] = [] | (a : [a])`.

Comment: I get "temp.hs:13:37: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Some :: a -> Maybe a

temp.hs:15:34: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      Some :: Iterator [] a -> Maybe (Iterator [] a)" here.

Comment: Note that the error message you quoted is talking about `[]` as the first argument of `Iterable`, not anything to do with `Iterator` or `ListIterator`. It says `[]` of kind `* -> *` (which is true), where it's expecting a type (which means something of kind `*`). leftaroundabout's answer explained why GHC was expecting that, but a careful read of the error message would have got you much closer to the right questions to be asking to debug this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the class does not really use its argument in any way at all, it only uses `Iterator c` but not `c` itself. That's ok in principle – `c` works basically just as a tag, to select some other type – though you should ask yourself whether that's really what you want and if a more direct approach wouldn't be better.

The only real problem: because `c` isn't used by itself, the compiler has no way of knowing what *kind* this should have. I.e., basically your class is *polymorphically kinded*, which Haskell98 doesn't allow... hence it defaults to the simplest possible kind, namely `*`. GHCi can tell you this:

```
*Main> :k Iterable
Iterable :: * -> Constraint
```

So that would work for e.g. `instance Iterable Int`, because `Int` has kind `*`. But `[]` doesn't, it has kind `* -> *`. Hence that error message.

You can enable GHC's `PolyKinds` extension to avoid this defaulting:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds     #-}

class Iterable c where
    data Iterator c :: * -> *
    current :: Iterator c a -> Maybe a
    next :: Iterator c a -> Maybe (Iterator c a)
```

Now it is

```
*Main> :k Iterable
Iterable :: k -> Constraint
```

and therefore both `instance Iterable Int` will work (with `k ~ *`) and `instance Iterable []` too (with `k ~ (* -> *)`).

Alternatively, you could manually state that `c` should always have kind `* -> *`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

class Iterable (c :: * -> *) where
    data Iterator c :: * -> *
    current :: Iterator c a -> Maybe a
    next :: Iterator c a -> Maybe (Iterator c a)
```

Now `instance Iterable []` would work, but `instance Iterable Int` wouldn't.

Comment: What do you mean with "c is not used"  - My intention was that ``c`` is the "container" type of kind `` * -> *`` and ``a`` is the element type of the container. Did I get it all wrong?

Comment: Yes... but you don't, for all the _class interface_ knows, ever contain anything in `c`, you merely use it as the argument of `Iterator`. Hence the compiler doesn't see any reason to infer the more complicated kind `* -> *` for `c`, and just picks `*` instead.

Comment: I like the kind signature idea as it expresses what I really mean in this case. But... my ``instance Iterable []`` is still not compiling for whatever obscure reason. Could you show me your instance version?

Comment: It's exactly the one you posted. Save for the `Some` obviously, that should certainly be `Just`?

Comment: I get "temp.hs:13:37: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Some :: a -> Maybe a

temp.hs:15:34: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      Some :: Iterator [] a -> Maybe (Iterator [] a)" here.

Comment: Gosh - this was a F# crossover... Its "Just" in haskell!

Comment: Right. [`some`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:some) is something different in Haskell...